# Dotenv file not giving variables NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

Im trying nextjs and i have encountered a problem. My path is like this

[image: first]

In connectToMongo my variable is coming

[image: second]

But when in `Main/index.tsx` my process.env is empty object

[image: third]

I also have problem when i push files to github .env file pushing too but i added it to .gitignore
My key is right, but dotenv is not seeing it
I tried to add

`dotenv.config({path: '.env'})`

But it not helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using Next.js, you don't need `dotenv` package. Next.js automatically imports the environment variables from `.env` or `.env.local` files. Also, only the variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix will be available on client side.